# I had installed the php trade extension on my macOs Mojave, but I'm not able to use it

Tags: php, macos, pecl

I installed **php** trade extension on my **macOS Mojave**. But I am not able to use it. I am sure it is installed because when I try to install it again it shows this:

> pecl/trader is already installed and is the same as the released
>   version 0.5.0 install failed

I already add in **php.ini** this:

```
extension=trader.so
```

But, I don't see my trader extension neither on terminal (`php -m`) nor on `phpinfo()`.

My **Php** version is - **PHP Version 7.2.10** and I'm using **XAMPP**.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?